# Resharper 5 - are speed & memory bloat issues solved?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2008, resharper-5.0, resharper-4.5

I am on Resharper 4.x and VS2008.

R# seems to slow down the living crap out of VS2008.  And of course, the memory usage can easily go to 500MB on a middle of the road Winforms solution with 7-8 projects.

Now that Resharper 5.x is out, can anyone tell me whether either perf or memory issues have been improved for use with VS2008?

Comment: Not really, but I think it's more or less "as designed". However there is a magic button that you can switch on/off and it will stop R# background activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe R#5 memory usage is better than the earlier versions but still too slow for me. I'm using it with VS2010 on a decent machine (quad core, 7200rpm HDD, 4GB ram). Using a solid state drive might help.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster, and not so hungry for RAM, but I have tweaked its code inspection a bit.

Comment: Can you share what you have tweaked that requires less RAM?  Last I checked Visual Studio 2010 the root cause was memory fragmentation caused by things like R#'s "Find Usages..." feature.  Whenever I use that feature a lot, I get out of memory exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Resharper 6.1, and there are still OutOfMemoryException issues.  JetBrains claims this is an issue with Visual Studio process fragmentation.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/OutOfMemoryException+Fix